# NSMutableDictionary setobject: forkey: crashes with unrecognised selector message

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

For the below code snippet:
error occurs at `setObject: forKey:`

```
response <--is an NSDictionary

if(response){
                NSMutableArray *lifeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                responseDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[response mutableCopy];
                [responseDict setObject:@"life" forKey:@"label"];   <-- Error here
}
```

Note that variable `responseDict` is `NSMutableDictionary` since copied via `mutableCopy`.

Error message:

```
2014-11-12 12:16:08.534 Lifetape[84381:508759] -[__NSCFArray setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a296700
2014-11-12 12:16:08.536 Lifetape[84381:508759] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a296700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x028fbdf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02557a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02903a75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0284c9c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0284c58e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Lifetape                            0x000dfb83 __50-[LTTimeLineTableViewController getTimeIntervals:]_block_invoke + 307
    6   Lifetape                            0x0014cedb -[MethodInvoker maybeInvokeCallback] + 395
    7   Lifetape                            0x0014d19f -[MethodInvoker receiveResultWithError:andResult:] + 399
    8   Lifetape                            0x00143e38 -[MeteorClient(Connection) livedata_result:] + 1544
    9   Lifetape                            0x00138674 __54-[MeteorClient(Connection) initConnectionWithOptions:]_block_invoke_3 + 2660
    10  Lifetape                            0x0014b2b5 -[MeteorClient didReceiveMessage:] + 197
    11  Lifetape                            0x0014eb7d -[ObjectiveDDP webSocket:didReceiveMessage:] + 269
    12  Lifetape                            0x0015d986 __30-[SRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke + 102
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x031e941a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03209e1f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x031f0981 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 610
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02855f3e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02814d40 __CFRunLoopRun + 2256
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x028141ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02813fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x051a524f GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x051a508c GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x00f41e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    23  Lifetape                            0x000ce36d main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x03235ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Update your question with a exact and complete error message. Details matter.

Comment: once use this line [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:response]; instead of (NSMutableDictionary *)[response mutableCopy];

Comment: before doing mutablecopy write the if condition [response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]

Comment: Read the error. `response` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: i think your `response` is `NSArray` check `if([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray Class]]) else if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary Class]])`

Answer (score 1):

Here your response dictionary is a NSDictionary type collection so it does not have any selector like setObject, that's why it is giving you this error use

```
if(response &&  [response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                NSMutableArray *lifeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:response];
                [responseDict setObject:@"life" forKey:@"label"];
}
```

and it will work but make sure response is your dictionary type object. as the error you have posted clearly says that your response is an array not a dictionary.

Comment: I am calling setObject on responseDict, which is NSMutableDictionary and not on response. mutableCopy gives you a NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: bro Means I think you response is an array not an dictionary

Comment: once check the response clearly i think it is an array not dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Your response looks like NSArray class so try below code.

```
if([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray Class]]){
NSLog(@"Array");
}
else if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary Class]]){
NSLog(@"Dictionary");
}
```

Now manage your code as per log.

Comment: Those two uses of `Class` should be lower case `class`